# Consolidate returned values on one line

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to join two tables, one with patient information and the other with surgery timings. I need to pull patient ID and 4 different timings that will vary for each patient. I am able to pull the data with the query below, but I'm running into an issue where my results include multiple entries for the same patient with results scattered on each. I believe the problem is tied to how my 2nd table is set up, but I'm not positive. I also have no way to change this.

All patients will have a unique visit_id for each visit so there will be no repeats.

I thought SELECT DISTINCT ON or GROUP BY would help resolve this but I haven't been able to get either of them to work in the way I need. The end goal is to get all pieces of data in their respective columns on the same line.

Sample data below:

Ex Table 1 (visit)

| visit_id | visit_name |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | Jim |
| 23456 | Dan |

Ex Table 2 (multi_app_documentation)

| nsma1_patnum | nsma1_code | nsma1_ans |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | ORINTIME | 0730 |
| 12345 | OROUT | 1030 |
| 12345 | surgstart | 0735 |
| 12345 | surgstop | 1025 |
| 23456 | ORINTIME | 0735 |
| 23456 | OROUT | 1035 |
| 23456 | surgstart | 0740 |
| 23456 | surgstop | 1030 |

Ex Results

| patinstitutionid | orentrytime | orexittime | incisionstarttime | skinclosuretime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 07:30:00 | NR | NR | NR |
| 12345 | NR | 10:30:00 | NR | NR |
| 12345 | NR | NR | 07:35:00 | NR |
| 12345 | NR | NR | NR | 10:25:00 |
| 23456 | 07:35:00 | NR | NR | NR |
| 23456 | NR | 10:35:00 | NR | NR |
| 23456 | NR | NR | 07:40:00 | NR |
| 23456 | NR | NR | NR | 10:30:00 |

```
select

v.visit_id as PatInstitutionID,

case --Add colons and seconds to time format
    when mAD.nsma1_code = 'ORINTIME'
        then concat(
            substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,1,2), ':',
            substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,3,2), ':',
            '00')
    else 'NR'
end as OREntryTime,

case --Add colons and seconds to time format
    when mAD.nsma1_code = 'OROUT'
        then concat(
            substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,1,2), ':',
            substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,3,2), ':',
            '00')
    else 'NR'
end as ORExitTime,

case --Add colons and seconds to time format
    when mAD.nsma1_code = 'surgstart'
        then concat(
            substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,1,2), ':',
            substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,3,2), ':',
            '00')
    else 'NR'
end as IncisionStartTime,

case --Add colons and seconds to time format
    when mAD.nsma1_code = 'surgstop'
        then concat(
            substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,1,2), ':',
            substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,3,2), ':',
            '00')
    else 'NR'
end as SkinClosureTime

from visit as v 
inner join multi_app_documentation as mAD
    on v.visit_id = nsma1_patnum and nsma1_arid = 5
where v.visit_arid = 5
and v.visit_admit_date > current_date - interval '60' day --Determines dates to pull using admit date
order by v.visit_id
```

Comment: Sorry if the tables are messed up... It doesn't look like that in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually pretty close. What you need is extract basically what you have and make that as a sub-query. The outer query then the takes the MAX for each column generated. The only significant difference being setting the 'NR' value, it is delayed to the outer query. In most cases it is probably not necessary but the resulting query leaves open the possibility that a code values is missing. Also the following does not use *visit_arid* nor the *visit_admit_date* columns. Those columns are NOT in your sample data. (Perhaps as a result of "messed up" sample tables.  
 See fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3205871749d2e2d3bae440919efab4a6)).

```
select  PatInstitutionID
     ,  coalesce( max(OREntryTime) , 'NR' ) OREntryTime 
     ,  coalesce( max(ORExitTime) , 'NR' )    ORExitTime
     ,  coalesce( max(IncisionStartTime) , 'NR' )   IncisionStartTime 
     ,  coalesce( max(SkinClosureTime) , 'NR' ) SkinClosureTime
   from ( select v.visit_id as PatInstitutionID 
               , case --Add colons and seconds to time format
                   when mAD.nsma1_code = 'ORINTIME'
                       then concat(
                           substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,1,2), ':',
                           substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,3,2), ':',
                           '00')
               end as OREntryTime 
               
               , case --Add colons and seconds to time format
                   when mAD.nsma1_code = 'OROUT'
                       then concat(
                           substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,1,2), ':',
                           substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,3,2), ':',
                           '00')
               end as ORExitTime,
               
               case --Add colons and seconds to time format
                   when mAD.nsma1_code = 'surgstart'
                       then concat(
                           substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,1,2), ':',
                           substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,3,2), ':',
                           '00')
               end as IncisionStartTime 
               
               , case --Add colons and seconds to time format
                   when mAD.nsma1_code = 'surgstop'
                       then concat(
                           substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,1,2), ':',
                           substring(mAD.nsma1_ans,3,2), ':',
                           '00')
                end as SkinClosureTime
          
             from visit as v 
             inner join multi_app_documentation as mAD
              on v.visit_id = nsma1_patnum
          ) i 
group by PatInstitutionID
order by PatInstitutionID;
```

NOTE: Be careful with CamelCase names. Unless you double quote them (") Postgres will fold then to lower case, so you get camelcase.

Comment: This did it! I appreciate the walkthrough, I understand it a bit better now.

Comment: Glad to help. Everyday I can add just a little bit of understanding  is a successful day.